# Probability of bike rack being filled given distributions of bikes leaving and returning

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Say we have $m$ spaces in a bike rack, which can be accessed by $n>m$ specific bikes. A bike leaves the rack at a random time $t$ according to a distribution $P_l(t)$ and returns a time $t'$ after leaving according to a distribution $P_r(t+t')$. Both distributions are periodic with 24 hours, i.e., the probabilities "reset" after 24 hours. 
> At any time, what is the probability that the rack is filled?

I'm mostly interested in how such a calculation can be set up and carried out. I haven't had much exposure to random variables and probability distributions, but I'd very much like to be able to handle questions as the one above myself. If you'd go through the calculations stating what theorems/methods are used along the way (so I can read up on it), I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It seems that $P_l$ and $P_r$ must be dependent? Otherwise it seems we could have $t'\lt0$.

Comment: @joriki Yeah, that's what I thought as well.